# What eclipse API should I use to access the dom tree of a jsp file?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I would like to have programmatic access to the dom tree of jsp files within the eclipse workspace. What eclipse API should I use therefore?

The bundle org.eclipse.jst.jsp.core contains a `JSPSourceParser`. But it is in an internal package and therefore not accessible.

It would be nice if the solution works with the Helios release.

Comment: Why do you want an Eclipse API and not any API that could parse JSP?

Comment: @stonedsquirrel I'm restricted on the tools I can access. And I have a Helios installation with a JSP editor. So there should be a way to access the JSP dom tree from within my eclipse installation. However I haven't managed to find the API for that.

Comment: Just because it has the functionality it does not mean that it offers an API. Is there really no way to use an external library with your project? Otherwise your application might have to ship with whole Eclipse modules.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is just for analysis purposes. That is not deployed anywhere. The process of getting some jar to a dev here is just taking ways too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, since we put it together some 13 years ago, there's a conflict between being binary compatible and having a fully clean and public API (moving interconnected Interfaces is *hard*).  What's there is "provisional", but unlikely to change.

See http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/wst/components/sse/overview.html (plus http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=64634/) and start with references to the SSE IModelManager class (plus the JavaDoc for that class) for obtaining the IDOMModel.  The parser class you saw works at the syntax level. It's used by the code that builds the DOM, but it does not build a DOM itself.